# FullCalendar - avoid scroll bars

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using Fullcalendar (daygrid) with a width of 250px.

When it renders, the height of `.fc-day-grid-container` is getting set at some random number and scroll bars appear.

The css is `style="overflow: hidden scroll;height: 203px;"`

How can I prevent the height getting set?

Is it possible to run the below after the calendar has loaded?

```
$('.fc-day-grid-container').removeAttr("style");
$('.fc-widget-header').removeAttr("style");
```

p.s.
the `main.css` file has the below styles which are getting overriden:

```
.fc-day-grid-container,.fc-scroller,.fc-time-grid-container{
    overflow:visible!important;
    height:auto!important
}
```

Comment: " the height of .fc-day-grid-container is getting set at some random number". It's not random at all. As per the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height), if you don't specify a height for the calendar, its height is calculated according to the [aspectRatio](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio) setting as a ratio of width to height. The height of the actual grid within the calendar is controlled specifically by the [contentHeight](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight) setting as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set height on 'auto'

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  height: 'auto'
});
```

Source : [FullCalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below to my custom css has fixed the issue:

```
.fc-day-grid-container{
   overflow:visible!important;height:auto!important
}
```